# Доступ к сайту через прокси ASP.NET

Tags: c#, proxy, asp.net-core-mvc

```
public IActionResult Page()
{
  var url = "https://docs.microsoft.com";
  var proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy address:port/", false);
  proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
  var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
  httpClientHandler.Proxy = proxy;
  var client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
  return Redirect(client.BaseAddress.ToString());
```

Переходит на сайт, но без прокси (хотя когда задаю настройки прокси явно через windows настройки на этот же сайт доступа нет)
Как можно проверить используется ли при этом сам прокси? А то может все работает, а я поднял шумиху

Comment: 1) Прокси не имеет отношения никакого к переадресациям. Либо переформулируйте вопрос, вдруг я не так понял. 2) `HttpWebRequest` устарел лет 10 назад, используйте `HttpClient`. 3) При чем здесь ASP.NET Core 6 (ASP.NET 6 не бывает)?

Comment: @aepot 1) Я не понимаю, достаточно настроить прокси при помощи `HttpClient`, а потом обращаться к сайту и автоматически запрос-ответ будет идти через прокси? (мне нужно обратиться к сайту через прокси сервер) 2) Я только позавчера сел изучать ASP.NET спасибо), 3) ASP.NET 6 core корректнее

Comment: Прокся какая HTTP или SOCKS? Вы хотите с сервера обратиться к другому сайту из метода контроллера, верно?

Comment: @aepot 1) http, 2) да

Comment: Покажите метод контроллера целиком, это нужно для ответа. Кстати `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` это вообще зачем? У вас прокся с паролем? Не отвечайте в комментах, внесите всю информацию в сам вопрос.

Comment: @aepot Исправил

Comment: О, я понял, что нужно, и нет,не получится так сделать. Невозможно держать подключение к прокси на стороне сервера, оно возможно только на стороне клиента. То есть вы можете пробросить данные, например вывести на своей странице полученные данные, но не сможете пробросить само подключение на браузер. Чтобы сделать то что хотите, вам нужен свой прокси-сервер, но не веб-сервер.